# Regex to extract mathematical variables in equation

Tags: java, regex

I have a mathematical expression given as a `String` and I have to extract all the variables which are identified as a letter, possibly followed by a number (e.g `x` or `x0`). It works for simple expressions but if I try it with a more complicated equation I pick also numbers which I don't want since my goal is to determinate if the two equations use the same variables.

```
     String expression = "((x0+(2.0^x))/(21.1-x0))";
     for (String variable : expression.split("[^a-z0-9?]")) {
       if(!variable.isEmpty()){
         System.out.print(variable + " ");
     };
```

and the output is:

```
x0 2 0 x 21 1 x0
```

where I wanted

```
x0 x x0
```

why it takes also digits without a letter before? I already tried every possible combination of `\\b` and I didn't find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression keeps the digits because they are not included in the regex search for the `split` method when creating the `String variable`.

Try splitting at one or many non-alphanumeric characters (`\W+`), which may be followed by zero or many digits (`\d*`).

`"\W+\d*"`

Adding `\d*` to the end of your existing regex should also work.

`"[^a-z0-9?]\d*"`

Tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4VAk3a/2) with Java 8.

Please let me know whether this resolved your question.

Comment: Thank you this was the cause...you saved my night thank you! Unfortunately i still can't upvote but as soon as i will be able i will! Thank you once more!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of splitting on what you don't want, you can also match what you are looking for.

```
\b[a-z]\d*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LaYJmG/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/tVmysq)

```
String regex = "\\b[a-z]\\d*\\b";
String s = "((x0+(2.0^x))/(21.1-x0))";
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}

for (String match : matches) {
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

Output

```
x0
x
x0
```